# Excel sum row's corresponding row values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's a sample Excel sheet:

```html
x y
---------
a 5
b 4
a 6
a 8
b 4
b 6
a 3
c 1
c 2
```

I'd like to get the summation of corresponding values from column x.

For example a = 5+6+8+3 so the summation of corresponding values of a = 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [SUMIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php)?

> SUMIF( range, criteria, [sum_range] )

You can use, for instance:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A9, "a", B1:B9)
```

To sum all values in column B which corresponding value from column A is "a".

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
=SUMIF(X1:X10,"=a",Y1:Y10)
```

Adjust your ranges accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your sample to Excel and verified:

`=SUMIF(A2:A10,"a",B2:B10)`